# Python: using Gensim and Scikit in the same pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim

I would like to use Gensim and Scikit in the same pipeline.

**[Update]**
Corpus is created from a list of lemmatized tokens `doc.tokens`

```
bowlist = []
for doc in linked_doc_list:
    bowlist.append(doc.tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(bowlist)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(line) for line in bowlist]
```

This involves transforming the Gensim corpus to a numpy array like so:

```
 numpy_matrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2dense(package.corpus, num_terms=len(package.dict.token2id))
```

This seems to work. The sklearn lda runs:

```
model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=components,
                                          max_iter=maxiter,
                                          learning_method=learningmethod,
                                          learning_offset=learningoffset,
                                          random_state=randomstate,
                                          verbose=verbose).fit(numpy_matrix)
```

But now, to read the results, I need to read the actual terms from the gensim dict (otherwise I am stuck with meaningless feature numbers).

However, the results from the following code are clearly meaningless.

```
 def filterAndReportResultsLDA(self, model, gensimdict, n_top_words=10):
     for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
         print("Topic %d:" % (topic_idx))
         words = []
         for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]:
            words.append(gensimdict[i])
         print(words)
```

Example result is:

```
['reporting.', '7:23', 'users?', 'breaking', '5am', 'bell', 'c7n', 'content?', 'functions', 'vi']
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you add, how are you defining `package.corpus` ?

Comment: updated :) Thanks for your attention

Comment: stil your question is not complete. Explain how are your creating numpy_matrix and what is the current ouput/error!

Comment: again, thank you. Gensim has a tool for converting to nupy array:
numpy_matrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2dense(package.corpus, num_terms=len(package.dict.token2id))

Comment: there is no error. But the results (see example) are obviously incoherent

Comment: Understood. I think the problem is with your text cleaning (you are not removing the punctuation, digits, etc.). There seems to be no issue with your current code.

Comment: May be this [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.html) could be useful

Comment: how is ```gensimdict```constructed ?

Comment: thanks. i am working on the cleaning. gensimdict is simply a reference to corpora.Dictionary(bowlist)